# Python selenium | How to fetch all the drop down list values using index , Complex drop down structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I'm using python selenium, I want to fetch all the values from the drop-down which displays in the main screen, Drop down values are dynamic based on another dropdown selection

I have tried the following code

```
try:
    element = find_element_by_locator(self, locator_type, locator)
    print " -- Drop Down available values :"
    for option in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        print " -- ", option.text
        if option.text in select_text_option:
            option.click()
except TimeoutException:
    ex_message = " ** failed to get drop down value for " , select_text_option
    print ex_message
    raise Exception(ex_message)
```

I'm getting null value as output :

```
<select chosendataplaceholder="Choose Finance Product" class="chosen-select-width" error_target_sel="#evo_lead_evo_finance_product_id_err" name="evo_lead_evo_finance_product_id" data-placeholder="Choose Finance Product" style="display: none;">
  <option selected="" value="1">Novated Finance Lease - Allowed</option>
  <option value="2">Finance Lease - Not Allowed</option>
  <option value="3">Novated Operating Lease - Not Allowed</option>
  <option value="7">Chattel Mortgage - Not Allowed</option>
  <option value="9">Consumer Loan - Not Allowed</option>
  <option value="10">Associate Lease - Not Allowed</option>
  <option value="11">No Finance (Car Only) - Not Allowed</option>
</select>
```

I want to fetch all the available values from the drop-down in my code so that I will do some logic function to send what will be the next drop down values, Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle `<select>` dropdown is with `Select` class

```
element = find_element_by_name('evo_lead_evo_finance_product_id')
select = Select(element)

# select an option by text
select.select_by_visible_text(select_text_option)

# get all options text
for option in select.options:
    print " -- ", option.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tag name you can try this xpath, though it's working in my system :

```
dropdown_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='evo_lead_evo_finance_product_id']/option")
for element in dropdown_elements:
 print(element.text)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To get the text of all the options use the below code :

```
listele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='evo_lead_evo_finance_product_id']/option")

for i  in range(len(listele)):
    print(listele[i].text)
```